# AndroidstudioにてNo such file or directoryエラーが出ます。

Tags: android-studio

こちら（スタックオーバーフロー）での質問は初めてとなります、よろしくお願いします。
私はAndroidStudioにて署名付きAPKファイルを作成し、そのテストを行いました。すると、AndroidStudioは`adb: error: cannot stat 'app-release.apk': No such file or directory`というエラーを出してきました。しかし、このapp-release.apkファイルはappディレクトリ配下に配置されているのが目視で確認できる状態で、ないということはないはずなのです。私は様々なサイトで原因の解説になるようなものがないか探しましたが力及ばず全く見つかりませんでした。なので、既に半日前ほどに投稿しているteratailとのマルチポストとなりますが、ここで質問させて頂きます。よろしくお願いします。

### 追記

Build>Generate Signed APKからダイアログを出し、Nextを選択してチェックボックスのV2にもチェックを施して更新したところ、`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

 Keystore file C:\Users\shoic\Desktop\keyindex\mrgbounding.jks not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.`というエラーが発生しました。何か関連があるかもしれないので追記しておきます。
※その後、Choose existing ボタンを選択し、再度ビルド？すると追記のエラーは無くなりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。原因は分かりませんが、解決方法としてはアプリケーション名配下に直接apkファイルを置くことでサクセスしました。